# php parameters over specific port

Tags: php, http

I have a php page http://mydomain.com/mypage.php
this page will be accessible by public and our partner.
my partner is supposed to send a POST request over port 7333 to http://mydomain.com:7333/mypage.php .
now how can i accept the parameters if and only if they came over port 7333.
i want to distinguish between parameters that are coming from our partner from params sent by a hacker

Thank you

Comment: Using a port to distinguish traffic is bad, whats to say Hacker Joe doesn't send his data over port 7333 also?  I would suggest a SOAP/Rest service with authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set up your web server to listen on that port.

See [Running different sites on different ports](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#port) in the Apache manual

This is not possible without system administrator privileges.

Also, it's not good to use a non-standard port for security, at least not if it's the only protection. You should implement some sort of authentication instead!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you let the partner send something like `data=[...]&secret=gfhshjkfbdnfgezur` to the normal port instead? This string would be the same every time and you would check whether it's the correct one.